# OnBlur/onChange attributes not showing in Chrome dev tool

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, onchange, onblur

OnBlur attribute not showing in Chrome dev tool.
This is my React code:

```
 <Input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" value={this.state.firstname} onChange={this.handleInputChange} onBlur={this.handleBlur('firstname')} valid={errors.firstname===''} invalid={errors.firstname !==''}/>
```

As you can see from the picture, both On Change/On Blur are not show there nor in the DOM structure Nor in the events listener! Where can I find them? why they are not shown up?

[CLICK HERE TO SEE THE PICTURE ATTACHED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mks8.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can try oninput event the onblur event only work when you click out of element

Comment: Of course I have tried! It does show only the "invalid" Event handler...
Can you post a picture where does it show to you?